# How to run the script after the load method of JQuery run?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, async-await

I have a code that do a load in Jquery and loads a page and after this page has been loaded I have to execute some functions, but the functions is been runned before all the page has been loaded, giving me a error.

```
async function edit_matrix(id){
    const response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/apps/edit/matrix/${parseInt(id)}`)
    const data = await response.json()
    if(data.determinant){
        $(".cont").load("http://127.0.0.1:8000/apps/determinant");
        console.log("JQuery")
        $(document).ready( 
            select_grid(data.number_rows_a) //The code that must be executed after the load of the page
        ); 
        
    }else{
        //another part of the code
    }
}
```

I try to add the await element to make the code stop and just run before that actions ends and I tried to add the method ready of Jquery, but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a callback function with in load ();

```
$(".cont").load("http://127.0.0.1:8000/apps/determinant", function() {
    console.log("Content loaded!");
    select_grid(data.number_rows_a);  // Execute code after content is loaded
});
```